# Python timing a socket connection

Tags: python, windows, sockets, network-programming

I am looking to get the time taken to complete a round trip to a server using TCP. When using a windows client.
(I would use ping but the server is blocking this)

I am looking at using python and sockets to complete this and I currently have.

```
import time
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )

start = time.time()
s.connect(('localhost',80))
print 'time taken ', time.time()-start ,' seconds'

s.close()
```

The issue I have is I do not think the connection timer is working as I am regularly getting the same time stamp returned. Could someone point me in the right direction to sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, the `time.time()` value does not have enough granularity (only 1/60th of a second). Use [`time.perf_counter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) which on Windows has about 1/3rd of a microsecond resolution, instead:

```
start = time.perf_counter()
s.connect(('localhost',80))
print 'time taken ', time.perf_counter()-start ,' seconds'
```

This is the same timer that the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) uses; you could use the [.default_timer()](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) definition instead:

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()
# etc.
```

This also works on Python 2, where `time.perf_counter()` is not available, but  [`timeit.default_timer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) will reference the best-available timer for your OS (`time.clock()` on Windows, which there has about 1/100th of a second resolution, `time.time()` on other systems).

Comment: That was exactly the issue. It was the granularity of the time functions. Thanks

Comment: +1 for `timeit` module. I'm on Linux, so not the question focus, but I had no luck with `time.time()`, `time.clock()`, or even `time.perf_counter()`. I kept seeing very different results than Wireshark measured. But `timeit.default_timer()` gives results very close to what Wireshark shows.

Comment: Actually, in Python 3.3+, `timeit.default_timer` is defined as `time.perf_counter`. I may have made a mistake in the `time.perf_counter` measurements. But I've done some more, and `time.clock` and `time.time` definitely give wrong answers sometimes, while I haven't seen `time.perf_counter` or `timeit.default_timer` be wrong.

Comment: @NickS: this answer is over 5 years old, Python 3.3 didn't come out until after I wrote this, and Python 2 was still where all the action was. :-) I'll update the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, should have made clear that was a correction to my first comment. I mainly wanted to say that I appreciate the pointer to `timeit.default_timer()`, since I'd realized how inaccurate other methods can be.

Comment: @NickS: not a problem, it alerted me to an outdated answer, so it led to an opportunity to improve things. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

With the following modified script I get the same results as `ping` on Windows 7.

```
import time
import socket
while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
    start = time.time()
    s.connect(('www.google.at',80))
    print 'time taken ', (time.time()-start)*1000 ,' ms'
    s.close()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Pinging my localhost always gives me the same very small value. This could be the problem.